# Getting values from json arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I am trying to get data from https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XBTUSD&interval=1 to my database, but I'm having issues with the array. 
I want to get the last datetime in unix, but it just doesnt work.

here is how I try to get the value, but it just seems to not be working:

```
var cur = body.length - 1;
var time = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][0];
```

Comment: looks like `cur` should be `body.result.XXBTZUSD.length - 1`

Comment: Here is a working example of Pointy's suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/797nnpw5/1/

The code is working fine with this fix.

Comment: here is my code:
`var cur = body.result.XXBTZUSD.length -1;
var time = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][0];
var high = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][2];
var low = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][3];
var open = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][1];
var close = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][4];
var volume = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][6];`
Result:
Row 1:
1499279760
kraken.com
BTC
USD
2601.027
2601.001
2601.026
2601.027
5.99425277
Row 2:
1499279820
kraken.com
BTC
USD
2601.042
2601.042
2601.042
2601.042
0.0371
Row 3:
1499279880
kraken.com
BTC
USD
2606.789
2603.719
2604.045
2606.789
0.68261

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
// this one will return 1 because the length are 'error' and 'result' 
var cur = body.length - 1;
```

You need to

```
var cur = body.result.XXBTZUSD.length - 1;
var time = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][0];
```